# Running three Tkinter applications from single file

Tags: python, multithreading, file, tkinter

I want to run 3 python file that contains Tkinter application for each one of them.
The issue that 3 files located in 3 different locations on the PC.

I succeeded to put the files in 2 functions that run when it called but the problem that when I run the script it waits for the first Tkinter window to close and then runs the rest application.

The code :

```
def openRegisterApplication():
    os.chdir(dirsFolderToChdir['GUI'])
    os.system(f'python {expectedRegister_Application}')
def openBackEnd():
    os.chdir(dirsFolderToChdir['FaceR'])
    os.system(f'python {expectedFaceR_cam_1} & python {expectedGUI_Deshboard}')
Thread(target = openRegisterApplication()).start()
Thread(target = openBackEnd()).start()
```

Comment: Change `Thread(target=XXX())` to `Thread(target=XXX)`. The former one will execute `XXX()` in main thread immediately.  Or use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.system()`, then don't need `threading`.

Comment: It works! Thanks !!